# puppet agent --test throwing environment errors

Tags: puppet

I am trying to keep puppet master and client/agent on one machine. I have been trying this for last 2 days and I am almost close to finishing it.

1) started puppet master "service puppetmaster start". Its successful
2) started puppet agent "service puppet start. Its successful
3) When I try puppet agent --test. see the errors below

This is the error I am getting when I try "puppet agent --test". I tried setting different values for environment in puppet.conf file and also passing from command line args for environment but nothing seems to be working.

> Warning: Local environment: "production" doesn't match server
>   specified environment "none", restarting agent run with environment
>   "none"

I googled and tried what people said, but no use. It might work if I try agent from one machine and master on the other. But I want to make it work on one machine.

Comment: How have you installed the puppet components? using root or another user?

Comment: what puppet components? yes I am doing with root access

Comment: By components I mean puppetserver and puppet agent. If you want to make it work on one machine you don't use puppet agent -t. you should use puppet apply. here is a reference `https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/man/apply.html`

Comment: I tried puppet apply -t. It's not giving any logs, keep waiting... :(

Comment: what will be the expected output

Comment: https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/re‌​ference/man/‌​apply.html. This link is not active

Comment: forget about the `-t`  option. just create a site.pp file inside your `manifests` folder inside your production environment and specify the classes which you want to be included like `include 'nginx'` and then apply the code like:
`puppet apply {your_puppet_code_directory}/manifests/site.pp`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121759/discussion-between-arun-and-miad-abrin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make it work on one machine you don't use puppet agent -t. you should use puppet apply. here is a reference 
`https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/re‌​ference/man/‌​apply.html`

Answer (score 0):

you can write a small script which will be having `puppet apply` command with farther argument (of course) and you can name it whatever you want (e.g: Papply) and run it every time whenever you want to run `puppet agent -t`.
`puppet agent -t` is not preferred for stand alone Puppet Server & Clint environment.
https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.6/reference/architecture.html